# AWS giving access to An IAM user to write to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Ok i have a bucket which 
only allows write access to users in the list

im using java to write and send files to my bucket
using my root account access and secret key i am able to put files in the bucket

but when i try to use the IAM users access keys it denies me(this is cause of the bucket rule i set)... i wont to know how i can add the user to my bucket access list

i have gone into the IAM users account and tried to get the canonical user id but i cant find it ..the account only allows me change password

and i really dont want to set my bucket permission to any authenticated aws user

any inputs would be greatly appreciated

Thank you

FYI: im using dummy code that writes  around 500 files and puts them in the bucket.. with my root account access keys it works fine

Comment: Where is the code being executed from? What you are doing here is really REALLY dangerous... Take a step back and consult with an expert...

Comment: @Henry im just trying to understand aws ..im using dummy code that writes files to a temp directory and then puts them in the bucket   right now the root account is mine   what i want to do is allow a sub user that i created to access and write files to the bucket  and like stated above i want my bucket to be exclusive to only users i allow

Comment: everything works fine for my root account just the way i want...im able to read and write these files.. but i want for a sub account that way the sub account can only be used t write fles to the bucket

Comment: Okay. you need to set up the new sub account, and associate certain *IAM Policies* with it. For example, S3FullAccess. You can generate custom policies, and Access Control Lists on the S3 bucket, to restrict what actions your user can do, and where it can do it. Dummy code is okay, but do be aware that using access keys is really not recommended. You accidentally check it into GIT, people will find it and spin up Bitcoin mining instances on your account (for example).

Comment: ohh yea .. nono the actual code is never gonna see tan online or public version control environments ...Thanks for the tip though.  @Henry  another thing you mention that using access keys is not recommended  but using the bucket in an exclusive manner is my clients requirement .. i can only seem to find this as an approach to put the files to the bucket(think i may need to do some more (R&D).....

Comment: So I would look at something like API Gateway, using STS tokens, etc. There are a long range of ways of doing it without giving long term credentials to the end user, but rather, just short term credentials

Comment: You said "a sub account."  To clarify, you're actually referring to an IAM user created in the same account that owns the bucket, right?  IAM users are not sub-accounts, they are entities within the AWS account.  The root credentials are also not really an "account" in and of themselves they're the primary/super-privileged credentials for the account.  @Henry has some sound advice, but at the same time, what you are trying to familiarize yourself with is valid. It's (imho) not something you shouldn't even try, because the more you understand the options, the better-equipped you generally are.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I meant an IAM user. My one caution is that you really really dont want to even remotely think using master access keys is the 'default' path, always try to do it a different way!

Comment: yea im creating IAM users for different uses....currently im trying to check different approaches to the same solution just in case    @Michael-sqlbot thanks for informing me ..i assumed that they were sub users  but i know now that i was wrong...i use master key only when im testing my self for some new service  ..once i know its working (then i check out the different group policies)..i create an IAM and uses that users keys